# Thread method parameters not thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading

Lets say I have:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => MyThread(a, b));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
private void MyThread(int a, int b)
{
    MoreMethods(a, b);
}
```

How can I make this thread safe, ie, ensure that each parameter in MyThread method, and all subsequent method calls, remains the value of which it was called with?

Comment: Thread safety is not the problem here, the code simply doesn't pass the values you expected.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `a` and `b` are captured by the lambda.

Just make copies:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
    {
        int a2 = a, b2 = b;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => MyThread(a2, b2));
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Now `a2` and `b2` are captured but they have local scope.